# A base Activity holding a button

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application I want to add a button at a unique position doing the same function in all activities, so instead of adding the same code to all activities, I thought of making a base activity, and here it is.

```
mport android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
 public abstract class DefaultActivity extends Activity{

ImageButton b;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.default_activity);
    b = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ana fel base activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

But the button doesnt appear in the other activities although I made other activities extend **DefaultActivity**. So is there a way to make this happen? Thanks alot.

P.S: I don't want to use the actionBar.

Comment: Do you have the ImageButton in all layouts?

Comment: yes, This is my question, Can I just define a button in the layout of the base activity, and by that It appears on all activites that extends the base activity, or I should manually add this ImageButton to all layouts and copy the same pieces of code in all activities to do the same function?

Comment: You only need to declare the ImageButton in all layouts. Then the onClickListener will works. The id for the ImageButton should be @id for all layouts except default_activity layout which should be @+id

Comment: I did all of this, but unfortunately the onclick didnt work.

Comment: Can you post any one activity that extends Defautlt Activity that onClick didn't work. onCreate is enough

Comment: Excuse me, Don't I define the onClickListener in the Default Activity? I mean, in the other activities, I don't have to define an onClickListener for it because I already defined it in the Default Activity. Correct me if Im wrong please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29050/discussion-between-omar-hesham-and-hoan-nguyen)

Answer (score 0):

If your other activities call `setContentView(...)` with other layouts, then those layouts are going to be shown. If those layouts don't have your `ImageButton`, then you won't have an `ImageButton` on screen (layouts won't "nest" by calling `setContentView()` in both the `Activity` and it's superclass implementation). One solution is to use the `<include>` tag in your other layouts and have another layout file with just the ImageButton like so:

**res/layout/image_button.xml**

```
<ImageButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
/>
```

**res/layout/activity_main**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- more views ... -->

    <include android:layout="@layout/image_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If I use the `<include>` tag, I'll have to put the implementation of the `onclickListener` in every activity wont I?

Comment: You could potentially put it in the BaseActivity. But you'll want to make sure that whatever code sets the onClickListener of the button will always run *after* the `setContentView()` call (so that `findViewById()` finds the button).